# What is more preferable way of using psycog2 cursor?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

For handle `postgresql` I use python library `psycog2`.

To make a transactions I can choose between:

```
with psycopg2.connect(params) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
```

or

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(params) 
    cursor = con.cursor() 
    cursor.execute(sql)        
    con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        con.rollback()
```

What is way more preferable (in the terms of speed and thread safety)?

I guess the second one is some better because I can use `cursor` more times than in the first approach (when `cursor` is needed to created every time). But what about thread safety?

Comment: Review [offical docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html) for your questions regarding: Thread safety and re-using cursors. To reduce connection time, you could use a connection pooler, like [pgBoucher](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer)